# How to use dynamic block with lookup

Tags: azure, terraform

Here i'm planning to add advanced filters for azure event grid subscription and my understanding advanced filters only one added for the event grid, so I preferred to use **length** function to control same with variable map(var.advanced_filter). Here I'm having issue with second dynamic block getting error: lookup() requires a map as the first argument.

**main.tf**

```
dynamic "advanced_filter" {
    for_each = length(var.advanced_filter)>0 ?[1]:[0]
    content {

      dynamic "bool_equals" {
        for_each = lookup(var.advanced_filter,"bool_equals", "") != "" ? [1] : []
        content {
          key   = var.advanced_filter.bool_equals.key
          value = var.advanced_filter.bool_equals.value
        }
      }
     }
}
}
```

**variable.tf**

```
variable "advanced_filter" {
  type        = any
  description = "Adding advanced filters for azure event grid subscription"
  default = [{ bool_equals = {
    key = "True"
  value = "test" } }]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var.advanced_filter` is a **list of maps**, so you have to access individual maps in the list using indices, such as `0`, `1` and so for. Since you have only one element in the list, it should be:

```
for_each = lookup(var.advanced_filter[0], "bool_equals", "") != "" ? [1] : []
```

Comment: The above condition is working fine, If I need to iterate over multiple elements in list the above one is not working . I tried using [*] as well not working .Any suggestion on same ?

Comment: @hari989 Then it would be better to have actual map, not a list of maps. Your question does not provide any example of the use of multiple values.

Comment: Changed  from list(map()) to map() ,now this works fine. Thanks @Marcin.
Any way the above given solution also works fine when there is only one element in list.
So I accepted your answer.